# How to color huge xlsx files that cant be opened with xssf approch

Tags: java, excel, apache, out-of-memory, apache-poi

I currently write a java program that compares two different .xlsx tables and marks the errors within them in different colors.
Therefore I use the apache poi approach to realize that.
Due to the size of the tables (> 20mb) I have to read them with sax parser to get the data.

I use the code below to create the cellstyles for my workbook.
As you see I need the "Workbook wbc" as input to create my cellstyles.

```
 public static CellStyle[] createColorStyles(String [][] fd_files, Workbook wbc) throws IOException{
    /*Diese Prozedur erstellt verschiedene CellStyles, die auf eine Xls Arbeitsmappe gewirkt werden können*/
    /*Öffnen des Workbooks indem die Cellstyles erstellt werden sollen*/    

    /* Zellstyle für ausgewähltes Workbook erstellen */
    CellStyle[] my_style = new CellStyle[4];
    my_style[0] = wbc.createCellStyle();
    my_style[1] = wbc.createCellStyle();
    my_style[2] = wbc.createCellStyle();
    my_style[3] = wbc.createCellStyle();
    /* spezifizieren der Hintergrund Farbe, sowie des Zellmusters */    

    //Auswahl für rote Zellfärbung
    my_style[0].setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND );
    my_style[0].setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());

    //Auswahl für gelbe Zellfärbung
    my_style[1].setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND );
    my_style[1].setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());

    //Auswahl für grüne Zellfärbung
    my_style[2].setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND );
    my_style[2].setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());

    //Auswahl für orange Zellfärbung
    my_style[3].setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND );
    my_style[3].setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.ORANGE.getIndex());
    return my_style;
}
```

However when it comes to color the differences I have the problem that I am not able to create a cellstyle for the workbook because I first need to open the .xlsx (as seen below)
Since there is not enough heapspace, I am not able to open the workbook and hence the cellstyle and color the document.

Below you see the code I am using to open the workbook to pass to the cellstyle method.
Unfortunately I always get an outOfMemoryError while trying to open the file.

```
public static Workbook openData(String [][] fd_files,int i) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

    // Hilfsprozedur, zum Öffnen eines übergebenen Workbookspfades (fd_files) 
    // übergibt geöffnet des Workbook, das für Bearbeitung bereit ist

    /*Deklaration lokaler Varibalen*/   
    Workbook wb = null;

    File file = new File(fd_files[i][3]);
    OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(file);

    wb =WorkbookFactory.create(opcPackage); 

    return wb;
}
```

I have already set my heapspace to -Xmx1024m , which is my maximum.

Is there any way to apply colors or cellstyles to such a big workbook,
which only can processed by the sax parser?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a `HSSFWorkBook` from an `NPOIFSFileSystem` on an `Inputstream` on your source file, adding your styles, then writing to an OutputStream (instead of using `XSSFWorkbook` and `OPCPackage` to manage your lifecycle) ?

```
// Both HSSFWorkbook that is event based, and NPOIFSFileSystem that uses nio should use less memory
HSSFWorkbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new NPOIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(pathToInputFile)));
CellStyle[] cellStyles = createColorStyles(fd_files, Workbook wb);
//...
wb.write(new FileOutputStream(pathToOutputFile));
```

If this does not work, I'm short on ideas... :-/

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. I tried your suggestion to integrate the SXSSF approach.

I might be wrong but, I thought that the SXSSFWorkbook is always just wrapped around another workbook class such as WorkbookFactory or the XSSFWorkbook.

My approaches were the following:

OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(file);
XSSFWorkbook test = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
SXSSFWorkbook wbt = new SXSSFWorkbook(test,100);  

--> OOM
and

Workbook wbs = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
wbs =WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fd_files[6][3]));

--> OOM

Is there maybe another way to use SXSSF ?

Comment: indeed my answer wasn't of any help in your case... I edit it hoping that it will be more helpful.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't that only possible for xls files but not for xlsx ?
However I will try your approach on first creating the file, create cellstyles from that and use its data-path as output for the copy of the file.
Maybe there is a slight chance that it works.

Comment: Unfortunately you're right again :-/ https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/ Sorry for that. I guess that I should delete my answer as it is completely useless (you can add to your question what you tried in order to help other people help you)